# Nightwatch Ajax request

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am having a `<label id=ajaxtest>Not ajax</label>` in the HTML page. After 5 seconds the label get changed to `<label id=ajaxtest>Called ajax</label>`

I am using nightwatch and trying to assert the text whether "Called ajax" is coming. I am new to nightwatch and kind of stuck how I can go. I tried few steps using asynch function and getText the label and nothing seems to work.

```
'Should display "Called ajax" message': (client) => {
home
.waitForElementVisible('@ajaxlabel',1000)
.assert.containsText('@ajaxlabel', 'not ajax');

client
.executeAsync(function(done) {
  (function fn(){

      // tried getText() here but the code is not working..
      return done("Finally");
   })();
}, [], function(result) {
  console.log("Inside Final:"+result.value);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the [before/after](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#expect-before) methods to accomplish this.

```
home.expect.element('@ajaxlabel').text.to.contain('Called ajax').after(5000);
```

Comment: Thanks..But what if the Ajax takes more time to complete. This is as good as adding a pause. Not sure if that can be used in standard practice?

Comment: Well, you said it would change after 5 seconds so that's why I put `5000ms`. Just pick something that is acceptable and go with that. If 5 seconds is what you want then write the test in such a way that it fails if the expected change doesn't happen after 5 seconds. If you draw a line in the sand of 5 seconds, and it takes 30 then the test should fail. And you should push back on the devs to improve performance so that it can get back under the 5 second limit you have set.